# Abas do Excel que foram salvas em html: como levar para cima

Tags: html, css, microsoft-excel, vba

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]Fiz uma planilha no excel com várias abas e depois salvei em html pois quero usar no meu site. As Abas da planilha ficam na parte inferior, o usuário do site teria que rolar até em baixo para dai trocar a aba que deseja, eu gostaria que as abas fossem colocadas para cima dentro da minha página de html. Obrigado,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ao salvar em formato HTML, é gerado um HTML com um *frameset* de duas *rows*, no padrão abaixo:

```
<frameset rows="*,39" border=0 width=0 frameborder=no framespacing=0>
 <frame src="bar_arquivos/sheet001.htm" name="frSheet">
 <frame src="bar_arquivos/tabstrip.htm" name="frTabs" marginwidth=0 marginheight=0>
 <noframes>
  <body>
   <p>Esta página usa quadros, mas o seu navegador não dá suporte para eles.</p>
  </body>
 </noframes>
</frameset>
```

O primeiro `frame` é a página onde é exibido o conteúdo das abas, e o segundo a página com o código das abas (`tabstrip.htm`).

Para mudar a posição, basta inverter a ordem dos frames e também inverter o `*,39`, ficando `39,*` (o valor `39` significa a altura em pixels do frame).

Então ficaria assim:

```
<frameset rows="39,*" border=0 width=0 frameborder=no framespacing=0>
 <frame src="bar_arquivos/tabstrip.htm" name="frTabs" marginwidth=0 marginheight=0>
 <frame src="bar_arquivos/sheet001.htm" name="frSheet">
 <noframes>
  <body>
   <p>Esta página usa quadros, mas o seu navegador não dá suporte para eles.</p>
  </body>
 </noframes>
</frameset>
```

Comment: Sam, muito obrigado mesmo! Estava muito tempo tentando descobrir isso!!

Comment: Bacana jovem. Se resolveu o problema, não deixe de privilegiar a resposta marcando ✔. Valeu!

Comment: Ordem e Progresso, rs, ce tái?